# YouTrack Gitlab integration creates wrong URL for commit hash

Tags: gitlab, youtrack

I've set up integration between YouTrack and Gitlab, and it is (mostly) working as expected.

We have multiple Youtrack project -> Gitlab Repo mappings configured, with the correct URL for the gitlab server.

When I add a commit hash into the comments, then YouTrack correctly identifies this as a commit hash, and turns it into a clickable link.

However, this link points to `https://[youtrackserver]/[reponame]/commit/[commithash]` where it should instead be pointing to `https://[gitlabserver]/[reponame]/commit/[commithash]`.  As a result, clicking on it give a 404.

In the past, this has worked (with the commithash URL pointing to the gitlab server), and then ceased to work, and then worked again.  I have no idea why, though we have had several upgrades of Youtrack in that time.

We can also set a one-to-many mapping from Youtrack Project to Gitlab Repos.  If I do this, then the generate commit hash link URL becomes `https://[youtrackserver]/rest/gitHub/checkCommit?issueId=[ticket]&sha=[commithash]` .  Clicking this simply gives a page with nothing on it but 'NotFound'.

How can I configure this to allow the commithashes to have a working URL?

Comment: Which YouTrack version are you using and which Gitlab (gitlab.com or self-hosted)? In any case, feel free to ask for help from the YouTrack support [here](https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66282).

Comment: @LiubovDievskaia Youtrack 2019.2 ; Gitlab self-hosted community 12.6.1